# HTML Table Fixed Header with Responsive Table Width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with no fixed `td` widths and `table` width set to 100%. I want the table header to be fixed. I have found many solutions for fixed width like this one: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew78t/3/light/)

But it doesnt work for fluid width table, and when you decrease the `viewport` size it fails to achieve the functionality.

Any way to achieve responsive fixed width header?

My HTML is like this:

```
<table class="delegations-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="del-head">
            <th>Région</th>
            <th>Ville / Quartier</th>
            <th>Lien</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Délégation de Rabat</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Délégation de Sale</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Délégation de Temara</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Délégation de Touraga</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
.del-contain {
    max-height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}   

.delegations-table {
    width: 94%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.delegations-table th {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    line-height: 2;
}

.delegations-table tr td a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.delegations-table tr.del-head {
    background: #3b8d3c!important;
}

.delegations-table td {padding: 5px 0 10px 18px;}
.delegations-table tr:hover {background: #ededed;}
.delegations-table td a {color: #000;}
.delegations-table td a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: added CSS please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution for this using CSS absolute positioning.

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u7vonqej/

**The HTML:**

```
  <div class="del-contain">
    <table class="delegations-table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="del-head">
                <th class="col1">Région</th>
                <th class="col2">Ville / Quartier</th>
                <th class="col3">Lien</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <br />
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Rabat</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Sale</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Temara</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Touraga</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de Rabat-Salé-Zemmour-Zaer</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Khemisset</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de du Grand Casablanca</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Mohammedia</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de du Grand Casablanca</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Mohammedia</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de du Grand Casablanca</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Mohammedia</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Région de du Grand Casablanca</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col2"><a href="#">Délégation de Mohammedia</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col3"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/del-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.del-contain {
    max-height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.delegations-table {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 260px;
}
.delegations-table th {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    line-height: 2;
}
.delegations-table tr td a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.delegations-table tr.del-head {
    background: #3b8d3c!important;
}
.delegations-table td {
    padding: 5px 0 10px 18px;
}
.delegations-table tr:hover {
    background: #ededed;
}
.delegations-table td a {
    color: #000;
}
.delegations-table td a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.delegations-table tr.no-bg {
    background: 0 none;
}
/*--- Fixed Header Table ----*/
 .delegations-table {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display:block;
}
.delegations-table thead {
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.delegations-table tbody {
    display:block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.delegations-table tr {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-top:-2px;
}
.delegations-table th {
    position:absolute;
    background: green;
}
.delegations-table td {
    display:inline-block;
}
.col1 {
    width:40%;
}
.col2 {
    width:30%;
}
.col3 {
    width:20%;
}
th.col1 {
    left:0px;
    right:80%;
}
th.col2 {
    left:40%;
    right:70%;
}
th.col3 {
    left:70%;
    right:50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 468px) {
    table.delegations-table th {
        height: 55px;
    }
    .delegations-table tbody {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .delegations-table .col2 {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .delegations-table .col3 {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The th and td are not aligned and have wildly different widths in this example.  Is there any responsive solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to resolve this with your own custom implementation, but the datatables plugin has fixed header responsive functionality that might be worth checking out.

http://datatables.net/